# Настройка кеширования на стороне клиента. Nginx + Apache 2

Tags: nginx, apache2, кэширование

[image: Заголовки HTTP]Есть сайт на хостинге. Нужно вывести в топ по Google Page Speed (не надо плеваться, так хочет клиент). Сайт работает на Nginx + Apache 2. Пробовал вставлять такую конструкцию в .htaccess :

```
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|js|css|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
```

Ноль результата.

Затем вставил в конфиг nginx.conf в http {} такую конструкцию:

```
server {
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|js|css|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        expires 1w;
        add_header Cache-Control private;

    }
}
```

Перезапустил nginx. Все прошло без ошибок. Затестил на валидность service nginx status - говорит все ок.

Но кеширования так и не происходит. Что делать не знаю, уже перерыл кучу статей, и перепробовал кучу вариантов.

Comment: покажи заголовки запроса в какой-то картинке, которая должна отдаваться из этого location-а

Comment: добавил картинку

Comment: по заголовкам видно, что кеширование не происходит. нужно убрать "Cache-Control private" и убедиться, что картинки раздаются именно тем location в котором стоит expires

Comment: То есть я удалю строку cache control И оставлю там только expires? А как убедиться что картинки раздаются именно тем location в котором стоит expires?

Comment: сначала нужно убедится, что картинки раздаются именно тем location, который вы конфигурируете. я бы закомментировал всё внутри и написал бы `return 200 'aaa';`. если при обращении по адресу картинки приходит текстовый ответ `aaa` - ок, настраиваем. если нет - разбираемся каким location отдаётся запрос и почему не отдаётся вашим

Comment: А возвращать он должен куда, в консоль Chrome?

Comment: что возвращает тот же запрос к той же картинке, что на скриншоте заголовков? `ааа`?

Comment: Да вроде все то же самое

Comment: то есть в браузере видна картинке? значит нужно разбираться как именно nginx раздаёт эту картинку

Comment: Окей, и как в этом разобраться?

Comment: Может мне просто прописать конкретный путь в location?

Comment: Думаю, что пришло время почитать документацию. Начиная, например, с простого http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html